# I read xrange is lazy it works at the last moment is it

Tags: python

I read this if we want to create a list of 1000000 numbers than using range(1000000) is not a cool idea because that will take a lot memory and soon as this range() is called it creates a list of that input size whereas xrange(1000000) would be better as it creates the values as needed

Say i have this little program:

```
for i in xrange(1000000):
        print i
```

Does this create the next position in the list every time the `for` loop is called not at the time when we called `xrange(1000000)` ?

Comment: There *is no list*. It just produces integers when iterated.

Comment: Please see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrange()` produces an object that only tracks the start, stop and step values. Nothing else.

Iterating then makes use of those values; the 5th element is always going to be `start + (5 * step)` anyway, so it [*just calculates that*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db95df7f309e/Objects/rangeobject.c#l114), rather than create a list like `range()` does.

To do this while iterating, a separate `rangeiterator` is created:

```
>>> xr = xrange(100)
>>> it = iter(xr)
>>> it
<rangeiterator object at 0x100660450>
>>> next(it)
0
>>> next(it)
1
```

The range iterator knows what step the iteration is at and asks `xrange()` to produce the next integer for that step.